# Why are duplicates considered so evil here?

Tags: discussion

I'm referencing [Pulling an Image from a Database vs pulling from a link to a directory](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6162/pulling-an-image-from-a-database-vs-pulling-from-a-link-to-a-directory)

It links "duplicate" posts that were made in Jan an April.  I'm not saying all these post are not related but really, why close discussion for newer posts that pop up?

1. People browsing/following SE might not have seen the previous posts since they entered the community
2. To close off a topic like that seems to indicate the end all of be all was fully addressed in previous topics.  This is never the case.
3. Especially when you're nearing a year there might have been significant changes in release versions that effect the validity of answers to come and could invalid previous answers

Comment: While I feel like adding something more to what Jeff has said would be productive, I'm just not sure what to add. This is actually the policy on the entire Stack Exchange network and is something that you would come across on [so], [programmers.se], [english.se] and all the rest of the sites here on the network. We strive to be a Question (Q) and Answer (A) site and many Q are the same, once distilled, while many A are universal for multiple Q. Yes, often the Q are left open to gain a few answers before being closed, and the community would know the answer to #3, thus preventing closing.

Answer (score 10):

> why close discussion

We don't do "discussion" here, if the questions are duplicates, that means the answers on two different questions are all valid answers for *both* questions.

And if that's so, why have multiple places to look for the answers?

Leaving a true duplicate question open is just making it harder for future visitors to find the answers they need.

We tolerate duplicate questions because people have an uncanny ability to ask the same question using zero, yes, *zero* words in common. Such is the expressiveness of human language.. I estimate it takes about 4-6 "duplicate" questions to cover all the different ways people will use language to ask the very same question.

See: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/

Comment: I presume you would suggest askers either place a bounty or do something else (like what?) to bump an old question they didn't find satisfying answers to.

Comment: Yes @Nick both of those things. Either place a bounty (we have a new and improved bounty system) or edit the question with a meaningful edit and that'll bump it to the top of the home-page.